# Match two arrays from a SOAP XML response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I searched around the internet in the last 2 days and I didn't found any solution to my problem,

I'm making a web application using PHP communicating with SOAP Web Services, and when I'm getting the respond of the Web Service I output the result in a few arrays, so now I want to match 1 array to another,

for example, I have array `$company` containing a list of 5 company locations, and then I have another array `$rates` containing a list of 37 rates and prices but I have to match each price in which location it belongs to, and I don't know how to do that.

I'm sorry for the long example I tried to make the shortest that I can, but I want you should understand what I mean

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Car_AvailabilityReply] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [availabilityDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [computeMarkups] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [actionRequestCode] => N
                                    )

                                [rateClass] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [criteriaSetType] => COR
                                    )

                                [companyLocationInfo] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [rentalLocation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [addressDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [line1] => 420 EAST 90TH STREET
                                                                    )
                                                                [locationDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC07
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [rentalLocation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [addressDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [line1] => 310 EAST 64TH STREET
                                                                    )

                                                                [locationDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [rentalLocation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [addressDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [line1] => 68 EAST 11TH STREET
                                                                    )

                                                                [locationDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC03
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [rates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [vehicleTypeInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [vehicleCharacteristic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => PUP
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC07
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => DOL
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC07
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [rateDetailsInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [tariffInfo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 100.68
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [vehicleTypeInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [vehicleCharacteristic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => PUP
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => DOL
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [rateDetailsInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [tariffInfo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 100.68
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [vehicleTypeInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [vehicleCharacteristic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => PUP
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC03
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => DOL
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC03
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [rateDetailsInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [tariffInfo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 100.68
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [vehicleTypeInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [vehicleCharacteristic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [vehicleRentalPrefType] => EDAR
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => PUP
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC03
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => DOL
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC03
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [rateDetailsInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [tariffInfo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 100.68
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [vehicleTypeInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [vehicleCharacteristic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [vehicleRentalPrefType] => EDAR
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [carCompanyData] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                                    )

                                                [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => PUP
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [locationType] => DOL
                                                                [locationDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [rateDetailsInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [tariffInfo] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [rateAmount] => 100.68
                                                                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                     )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

If you understand that you can see there is two type of arrays the first 3 is the location and the second is the cars with price, and I have to put each car to the correct location.

If you need more explanation please tell me.

Please help me out with that,
Thank you.

Comment: You might need a bit of your code to show what you're tring to do. The XML dump is one bit of info, but show the code you've got - as currently it's not clear.